# Ubuntu: Python3 check if file exists with subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I managed to install windows based network printer with python3 on ubuntu.

For better coding, I want to check first if the file with the drivers in it exists after the download. I know it is possible with `os.path.isfile` or something like that but I would like to do that with subprocess although os will not be supported in the future anymore.

So how do I do it? With subprocess.call or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

to check for a file to be present, You ideally use `pathlib`, which is the pythonic and portable way to interact with the filesystem.

But to avoid Time of Check to Time of Use Errors (TOCTTOU) You should consider:

Instead of :

```
if check_printer_present():
    # now, after checking the printer is present, 
    # the printer might go offline
    use_printer()
```

better use:

```
try:
  use_printer()
except PrinterError():
  printer_error_cleanup()
```

see:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-Check-to-Time-of-Use-Problem

You might remember that idiom as :

```
it's better to ask forgiveness than permission
(t is better to act decisively and apologize for it later 
than to seek approval to act and risk delay, objections, etc.)
```